# What are the letters in gcc inline assembly for %ebp and %esp?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

What are the letters in gcc-inline assembly for %esp and %ebp? 
I understand that:

```
a = eax 
b =ebx 
c = ecx 
d = edx 
S = esi 
D = edi 
I = constant value (0 to 31).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list in the manual for the [gcc machine constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints) (see under the : *Intel 386* section). The gory details (typically more up to date than the manual) are found in the [i386/constraints.md](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob_plain;f=gcc/config/i386/constraints.md;hb=HEAD) file.

**However** - for good reasons, namely stack coherency, `%ebp` and `%esp` cannot be used as constraints. They cannot be specified as inputs or outputs in extended asm syntax. This may also extend to `%ebx` in some cases - specifically, when generating position-independent code, e.g., with the (i386 SysV) ELF ABI.

You can still manipulate these registers in the asm block explicitly, of course.